# Each of them considered, "I miss her more than he.": is this use of "considered" grammatical?

Tags: word-usage

From a [story](http://lang-8.com/763639/journals/226199054380372412281826806721691324154) in which a man and a cat are left alone, for some time, by a woman:

> Each of them **considered**, "I miss her more than he."

Is this use of "consider" technically okay?

Looks not very natural, but Merriam-Webster's entry for "**[consider](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consider)**" does include the sense "to suppose".

Proofreading [texts](http://lang-8.com/763639/journals/226199054380372412281826806721691324154) written by English learners seems to be a good way of stumbling upon interesting questions.

Comment: @CarSmack, thank you, I almost slashed it out. (0:

Comment: Yes, it is technically okay. It is also quite good in a context like the original. When the woman departs and the man and the cat stay behind and they both consider, "I love her more than he." (continued)

Comment: In this context, *consider* means something like *regard* or *deem so* while *suppose* could be a bit weaker: *take for granted.* But they are close. Rarely are two words complete synonyms.

Comment: @CarSmack I wish to see the above in an answer. :-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "more than **him**"?

Comment: @Scimonster: I've added some context (the first line of the question).

Answer (score 1):

To use *considered* there would mean that they thought about the predication, not that they were thinking that thought. I believe that meaning is not what the author intended. I think the author wants to say "thought".

It's almost an e.e. cummings poem:

> The phone has rung unexpectedly...
>
> They had a long tongue about the cat.